# Pyodbc Error unixODBC Driver Manager Data source name not found in CircleCI

Tags: python, docker, odbc, pyodbc, circleci

I'm using CircleCI as a continuous integration pipeline. When CircleCI runs the build it starts a Docker container containing a PostgreSQL database and it executes a Python script which tries to connect to the database. The Python script fails with the following error:

> pyodbc.InterfaceError: ('IM002', '[IM002] [unixODBC][Driver Manager]Data source name not found, and no default driver specified (0) (SQLDriverConnect)')

[image]

Here is the Python script:

```
import pyodbc
conn = 'driver={PostgreSQL Unicode};server=0.0.0.0;port=5432;database=data_quality;pwd=password;uid=postgres;'
connection = pyodbc.connect(conn)
print('Success')
```

The file **/etc/odbcinst.ini** in the CircleCI VM contains the following configuration:

```
[PostgreSQL ANSI]
Description = ODBC driver for PostgreSQL (ANSI version)
Driver = /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/odbc/psqlodbca.so
Setup = /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/odbc/libodbcpsqlS.so
Debug = 0
CommLog = 1

[PostgreSQL Unicode]
Description = ODBC driver for PostgreSQL (Unicode version)
Driver = /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/odbc/psqlodbcw.so
Setup = /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/odbc/libodbcpsqlS.so
Debug = 0
CommLog = 1
```

I'm pretty sure the issue is because of the CircleCI configuration but I can't figure out why. Here is the CirclCI configuration file **.config.yml**

```
# .circleci/config.yml
version: 2
jobs:

  build:
    machine: true
    steps:
      - checkout

      - run:
          name: Create Docker Compose configuration file
          command: |
            echo "POSTGRES_USER=postgres" >> ./.env
            echo "POSTGRES_PASSWORD=password" >> ./.env
            echo "DATABASE_URL=postgres://postgres:password@db:5432/data_quality" >> ./.env

      - run:
          name: Build Docker images
          command: |
            docker volume create data-quality-db-volume
            docker-compose -f docker-compose.yml -f docker-compose.test.yml up db
            docker ps -a

      - run:
          name: Install Unix ODBC
          command: |
            sudo apt-get update
            sudo apt-get install -y g++ unixodbc-dev

      - run:
          name: Install PostgreSQL ODBC driver
          command: |
            sudo apt-get install -y odbc-postgresql

      - run:
          name: Move ODBC configuration file
          command: |
            sudo cp ./scripts/init/odbcinst.ini /etc
            cat /etc/odbcinst.ini

      - run:
          name: Install Python environment
          command: |
            sudo apt-get install software-properties-common
            sudo add-apt-repository ppa:deadsnakes/ppa
            sudo apt-get update
            sudo apt-get install python3.6
            sudo apt-get install python3-pip

      - run:
          name: Install Python dependencies
          command: |
            sudo pip3 install --upgrade pip
            sudo pip3 install pyodbc
            sudo pip3 install nose2 --ignore-installed six
            sudo pip3 list

      - run:
          name: Test Pyodbc connection to postgreSQL
          command: |
            echo 'export PYTHONPATH=./test:$PYTHONPATH' >> $BASH_ENV
            source $BASH_ENV
            nose2 --plugin nose2.plugins.junitxml --junit-xml -v

      - store_artifacts:
          path: test/junit/test-results.xml
          destination: test-results

      - store_test_results:
          path: test
```

Comment: A couple of things to look at: does `build` also do a `up` in Docker Compose?  I wonder if your database just is not running. Also, where does the host alias `db` come from? I appreciate that this DNS entry is created inside the Docker network created by Compose, but I don't think it is available in your VM. However in Compose you can publish a port, and then use `dockerize` (or any port tester) to wait for it to come up.

Comment: I wonder if your client needs to connect on `127.0.0.1` as well - if PostgreSQL is anything like MySQL, you need to ensure it does not try to use a Unix socket, as that won't work host->container.

Comment: Hi @halfer, you are right my compose was missing a `up` in my copy paste above. Your points are valid and I might face other issues while trying to connect to the db, however it seems I'm not even there yet as my Python script is not even able to find my ODBC configuration.